# My first NHibernate business app: how/when/where to use transactions?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, transactions, webforms, n-tier-architecture

I'm new to NHibernate but familar with EF4.

In a new business app with a new company, we've been instructed to use ASP.NET webforms and NHibernate, and I'm looking to get started.  I had planned to keep things nice and simple, and structure things as follows:

- Code-behinds calling Business Tier methods
- Business Tier classes taking "IRepository" references in the constructor, to faciliate unit testing
- Business Tier classes calling Repository methods, which return DTOs/collections of DTOs
- The Repositories would hide/encapsulate all the NHibernate stuff.

In terms of managing sessions/transactions, it hasn't been as easy as I expected  :)

Sessions: [this approach](http://pwigle.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/nhibernate-session-handling-in-aspnet-the-easy-way/) (using `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest` in global.asax) looks like the easiest way (I think?).... though I hadn't expected to have to put NHibernate code in my UI tier.

Now how to **use** those Sessions.....

This ["best practices" article](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/some-nhibernate-best-practices/) suggests I use this pattern for **all** NHibernate data access (even reads):

```
using (ITransaction tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    // execute a query, before an update, etc
    tx.Commit();
}
```

So my questions are:

- In my repositories, can I (and **should** I?) retrieve the current NHibernate session from HttpContext, as (I think) is suggested in [this approach](http://pwigle.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/nhibernate-session-handling-in-aspnet-the-easy-way/) ?  Doesn't seem right to me, as it is very UI-dependent.

(However that seems better to me than passing an NHibernate `ISession` object into the appropriate constructor, as I have seen used elsewhere.... i.e. in my case, I'd have to pass it from the UI through to the Business Tier constructor, then through to the Repository constructor.... and I'd hoped that the UI and Business Tier would be unaware of NHibernate.)

- In my situation, do I really need to wrap all my reads in a transaction?
- Is an "NHibernate" transaction any different to a "`System.Transactions`" transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a sense BeginRequest()/EndRequest() isn't really your UI code, but more of an "application-framework-kind-of-thing" that follows from how "requests" are handled in that particular style of application. If you want to reuse the same business tier in e.g. a native windows application you might want to handle your sessions differently, so it would not necessarily be a good idea to hide this completely in some sort of data layer.

You should likely use NHibernate's support for contextual sessions to track the active session per request. In your case, the WebSessionContext. http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture-current-session (Forget about ManagedWebSessionContext, it is deprecated.) Following this, you business/data layer will get the session from sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession(), and not depend on UI code.

Your UI should probably mostly be unaware of NH, except for application setup code in Global.asax. You can also move it to its own IHttpModule. You can of course hide it behind MyDataLayer.StartSession() if you really want to.

You should always use a transaction. What would you gain by not defining one? The database will still use (multiple) implicit transactions.

NHibernate transactions and System.Transaction are different. You can use TransactionScope, but you must in that case also use NH's transaction to avoid some problems.

Comment: Great answer. "Application framework kind of thing"?  Yep, agreed.

Comment: So would it makes sense to use NH transactions within every one of my Repository methods.... and then use TransactionScope occasionally in my Business Tier, where I want to group multiple Repository method calls into a single transaction? I suggest this only as it would allow my Business Tier to remain unaware of NHibernate.

Comment: Sounds wrong to put NH transaction handling in repositories - too fine grained. Also, since your business layer will presumably modify objects tracked by NHibernate, you must be careful to prevent some write from happening outside a NH transaction. But should your business tier care about transactions? How about making all calls from the UI to business layer be wrapped in a transaction?